# Typescript "Object literal may only specify known properties" not effects on Promise return function

Tags: javascript, typescript

Typescript will check unknown properties:

(below will have error: `"'c' does not exist in type..."`)

```js
interface IReturnVal {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

function oh(): IReturnVal {
    return {
        a: true,
        b: false,
        c: 1, // Type '{ a: true; b: false; c: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IReturnVal'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'c' does not exist in type 'IReturnVal'.ts(2322)
    };
}

oh();
```

**However if functions returning Promise**, Typescript will only check for missing properties

(below will have error: `"Property 'a' is missing in type..."`)

```js
interface IReturnVal {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

function ok(): Promise<IReturnVal> {
    //  Property 'a' is missing in type ....
    return Promise.resolve({
        b: false,
    });
}
ok();
```

**But not checking unknown properties**.

(below will **not** have any error or warning)

expect: Have error`"Object literal may only specify known properties..."`

```js
interface IReturnVal {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

function ok(): Promise<IReturnVal> {
    return Promise.resolve({
        a: true,
        b: false,
        c: 1, // will not cause any error or warning
    });
}
ok();
```

Is this the expect behavior or I'm missing something in Typescript setting?

Comment: Note that anything consuming `Promise<T>` can't access the `c` property anyway - it's not available via that interface, the compiler will prevent access to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it's not raising an error in your example is that your code isn't immediately returning an object literal, it's returning the result of calling a function. Excess property checks only apply to object literals. Since the function (`Promise.resolve`) is returning `Promise<{a: boolean, b: boolean, c: number}>` and that's assignment-compatible with `ok`'s `Promise<{a: boolean, b: boolean}>` return type, TypeScript doesn't complain.

You can make TypeScript check the object literal you're passing into `Promise.resolve` by providing a type argument to `Promise.resolve`:

```typescript
interface IReturnVal {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

function ok(): Promise<IReturnVal> {
    return Promise.resolve<IReturnVal>({
    //                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        a: true,
        b: false,
        c: 1, // <== error here as desired
    });
}
ok();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJICUJgK5RANTgBtkBvAKGSuTgC5kAjAeyaIjhAG5LqH7nW7LuQC+5cjGwgEYYExDImAawAUASnoAFKEwC2wAM4QAPBiy4CxAHxkeVKObzJtewxAB0Dg6wBuJszh4hERWKhTUyAD0kRGxcbEAeknJKUl2sXTIYFDYEAA06RF8yPBERgXxyAj0AIx5UTHGALxNyNA6UMgAFtAocAbIACYQBsAOg+kiatxiyurcQA)

Alternatively, you can make `ok` an `async` function:

```typescript
    interface IReturnVal {
        a: boolean;
        b: boolean;
    }
    async function ok(): Promise<IReturnVal> {
//  ^^^^^
        return {
            a: true,
            b: false,
            c: 1, // <== error here as desired
        };
    }
    ok();
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.3#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgEkBKMoFc4IA1JAG2AG8AoUW4JALmACMB7V0mJCAbhrpDMmbDl178QAXwn0AzgE8IKYAjxKoYVhGCsA1gAoAlEwAKcVgFswsmAB5suAsTIA+SlQD0HkAD0-fmVo4R0J3AQFGYCg4PBgAGkDwoRUyGwTwuhQmAEY44C9gWwBeIuB4czhgAAt4dCRZYAATGFkwYMbEqT5aaVo9Iz4gA)

For the avoidance of doubt: `async` functions always return promises. If you return a non-promise, it gets wrapped in a promise as though passed through `Promise.resolve`.